# ProxyError when using Luminati Proxy Manager

Tags: python, proxy, request

I am trying currently to scrape a website using a proxy. I chose to use Luminati as proxy provider.
I created a zone with a Data Center using Shared IPs.
[Luminati Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8JDf.png)

Then I installed Luminati Proxy Manager on my local machine, set up a proxy port using default config.

```
import requests
ip_json =  requests.get('http://lumtest.com/myip.json', proxies={"http":"http://localhost:24000/",
                                                     "https":"http://localhost:24000/"}).json()
proxy = "https://" + ip_json['ip'] + ':' + str(ip_json['asn']['asnum'])
proxies ={"https": proxy , "http": proxy }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


response = requests.get('http://google.com/', headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

However, each time I get

```
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=x): Max retries exceeded with url: http://google.com/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x11d3b5358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)))
```

I tried using urls with http and https however nothing changed. I tried putting the proxy address as https, but  still nothing.

Does anybody encountered this error and resolved it? I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, Luminati blocks google by default, and only allow specific use cases with the SERP zone.

Second, is google the only domain you target? Try lumtest.io/myip.json

The proxy manager should show you error codes in the logs, are there any clues there?

Try contacting Luminati live chat support from the control panel, you may have limitations on your account.